# Symfony2 sonataAdmin bundle for frontend user center

Tags: symfony, admin, frontend

We have a application base on symfony 2 and sonata-project(CMS ,admin ,user...) bundle and many other bundle. 
And we fund a amazing bundle ( sonataAdminBundle) , want to use it for our applicationuser customer center in the frontend, but it used by admin already.
how can i do? Someone could suggest some adivice?

Some difficult point where use two SonataAdminbundle in frontend and backend :
1. customer login session 
2. filter customer data
3. ACL for defferecent customer role
4. customize template

Last ,i said sorroy for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the option of using two SonataAdminBundle, though perhaps not impossible, you'll need a deep understanding of how to do it. I think what you need is to adapt the needs of the customers that will use the frontend and the users that will use the backend, to be the same in terms of templates and styles, and then surely will be far easier to find a configuration of roles and permissions to meet all the needs.